# summarize results dynamically produced by a template in R knitr

Tags: r, knitr, dynamic-reports, reproducible-research

I am writing a report using `knitr`, with a template that runs analyses
over multiple datasets (Section 1 of the MWE).

I can generate summaries of the results by assigning values to
variables that I then "stitch together" into tables (Section 2 of the
MWE). However, this approach is cumbersome and inflexible (e.g. lots
of typing to change what specific bits appear in the table).

How can I automate the production of the summary tables?

- Body of the report (MWE.Rnw):

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
  \section{Run tests}

  In this section we run the tests using a template.

  <<run-all, include = FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)

  ## set data names
  data_names <- LETTERS[1:3]

  ## initialize var for data
  data_1 <- NULL
  data_2 <- NULL

  ## initialize vars for chi-squared test results
  cs_statistic <- NULL                    # X-squared
  cs_parameter <- NULL                    # df
  cs_p_value <- NULL                      # p-value

  ## initialize vars for binomial test results
  bt_p_value <- NULL                      # p-value
  bt_estimate <- NULL                     # estimate
  bt_ci_lower <- NULL                     # conf. int. lower
  bt_ci_upper <- NULL                     # conf. int. upper

  ## run template
  src = NULL
  for (i in data_names) src = c(src, knit_expand('analysis-template.Rnw'))
  @

  \Sexpr{paste(knit(text = src), collapse = '\n')}

  \newpage
  \section{Summary}

  In this section we summarise the results.

  <<summary-cs>>=
  tab <- data.frame(data_1, data_2, round(cs_statistic, 3), cs_parameter, round(cs_p_value, 3), row.names = data_names)
  colnames(tab) <- c("var 1", "var 2", "X-squared", "d.f.", "p-value")

  kable(tab, caption = "Summary results of $\\chi^2$ tests")
  @ 

  <<summary-bt>>=
  tab <- data.frame(data_1, data_2, round(bt_estimate, 3), round(bt_ci_lower, 3), round(bt_ci_upper, 3), round(bt_p_value, 3), row.names = data_names)
  colnames(tab) <- c("var 1", "var 2", "estimate", "95% conf. int. (lower)", "95% conf. int. (upper)", "p-value")

  kable(tab, caption = "Summary results of binomial tests")
  @ 

  \end{document}
  ```
- Template (analysis-template.Rnw) called by MWE.Rnw:

  ```
  \subsection{Analysis of data {{i}}}

  <<analysis-{{i}}>>=
  ## generate data {{i}}
  (data_{{i}} <- sample(50:100, 2))

  ## run tests
  (cs <- chisq.test(data_{{i}}))
  (bt <- binom.test(data_{{i}}[1], sum(data_{{i}})))

  ## store results
  data_1 <- c(data_1, data_{{i}}[1])
  data_2 <- c(data_2, data_{{i}}[2])

  cs_statistic <- c(cs_statistic, cs$statistic)
  cs_parameter <- c(cs_parameter, cs$parameter)
  cs_p_value <- c(cs_p_value, cs$p.value)

  bt_estimate <- c(bt_estimate, bt$estimate)
  bt_ci_lower <- c(bt_ci_lower, bt$conf.int[1])
  bt_ci_upper <- c(bt_ci_upper, bt$conf.int[2])
  bt_p_value <- c(bt_p_value, bt$p.value)
  @
  ```